# How to split a string and store into array based on pattern in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a string like

```
string = ionworldionfriendsionPeople
```

How can I split it and store in to array based on the pattern **ion** as

```
array[0]=ionworld
array[1]=ionfriends
array[2]=ionPeople
```

I tried IFS but I am unable to split correctly. Can any one help on this.

Edit:
I tried

```
test=ionworldionfriendsionPeople

IFS='ion' read -ra array <<< "$test"
```

Also my string may sometimes contains spaces like

```
string = ionwo rldionfri endsionPeo ple
```

Comment: __How__ did you use IFS? What code have you written? In order to help, we need a little more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some POSIX parameter expansion operators to build up the array in reverse order.

```
foo=ionworldionfriendsionPeople
tmp="$foo"
while [[ -n $tmp ]]; do
    # tail is set to the result of dropping the shortest suffix
    # matching ion*
    tail=${tmp%ion*}
    # Drop everything from tmp matching the tail, then prepend
    # the result to the array
    array=("${tmp#$tail}" "${array[@]}")
    # Repeat with the tail, until its empty
    tmp="$tail"
done
```

The result is

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
ionworld
ionfriends
ionPeople
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -oP` with **lookahead regex**:

```
s='ionworldionfriendsionPeople'
grep -oP 'ion.*?(?=ion|$)' <<< "$s"
```

Will give output:

```
ionworld
ionfriends
ionPeople
```

To populate an array:

```
arr=()
while read -r; do
   arr+=("$REPLY")
done < <(grep -oP 'ion.*?(?=ion|$)' <<< "$s")
```

Check array content:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="ionworld" [1]="ionfriends" [2]="ionPeople")'
```

---

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (PCRE) then you can use this gnu-awk:

```
awk -v RS='ion' 'RT{p=RT} $1!=""{print p $1}' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
ionworld
ionfriends
ionPeople
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input string never contains whitespace, you can use parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
string=ionworldionfriendsionPeople
array=(${string//ion/ })
for m in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo ion"$m"
done
```

If the string contains whitespace, find another character and use it:

```
ifs=$IFS
IFS=@
array=(${string//ion/@})
IFS=$ifs
```

You'll need to skip the first element in the array which will be empty, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
# To split string :
# -----------------
string=ionworldionfriendsionPeople
echo "$string" | sed -e "s/\(.\)ion/\1\nion/g"

# To set in Array:
# ----------------
string=ionworldionfriendsionPeople
array=(`echo "$string" | sed -e "s/\(.\)ion/\1 ion/g"`)

# To check array content :
# ------------------------
echo ${array[*]}
```